# Application object triggers custom event twice? Marionette v1.1.0

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-events

I've a collection Days actually shared by 2 collections - collection view v1 for adding or removing days (edit) and composite view v2 that displays clickable links to navigate to the individual day's itemViews.

```
AppointmentManager = new Marionette.Application  //app object.
//sharing collection days among two views v1, v2.
var days = new Entities.Days(ApptModel.get("apptDays"));
var v1 = new EditCollectionView({collection: days});
var v2 = new ListCompositeView({collection: days});
```

To delete say appointments for day 2, user clicks on the delete button on dayItemView2 in collectionview v1, which also causes the day to be deleted from collection view v1, like so:

```
onDeleteDayClicked() {
    this.model.collection.remove(this.model);
}
```

This  deletion also gets reflected in the view v2, as collection is shared across these two views. Day 2's navigation link is deleted from v2 automatically by Marionette.

The collection Days listens on this remove event in initialize. To ensure that these changes are reflected and saved serverside (along with other bits of info stored as part of the larger model that also stores collection of days), I trigger on the application manager a save event:

```
 Entities.Days = Backbone.Collection.extend({
              initialize: function(options)    {
                    this.on("remove", function(model,collection,index) {
                            AppointmentManager.trigger("appts:save");
            }
});
```

However in my ApptController, I receive the apps:save event twice. I've checked that collection Days receives only one delete event and only one model is deleted , hence appts:save trigger is called ones.

```
    ApptManager.listenTo(ApptManager, "appts:save", function() {
        console.log("Saving appts!");
        appts.set("days", days);
        appts.save();
    });
```

"Saving appts" gets printed twice and appts PUT twice!

Any clues?!

Using Marionette v1.1.0.
I've got other modules and apps that display header navbar view and other pages. My application structure is based on Backbone.Marionette.js: A Gentle
Introduction by David Sulc - although I doubt if this packaging structure is of any relevance to this problem.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the `'appts:save'` event handler in `ApptManager`? It would be enlightening to know if / how the call stack looks different for the two calls.

Comment: The call stack is same.

Comment: Did you try @Tigra's suggestion of adding `console.log('init')` to `initialize`? I'd also add one to the  `remove` handler, to see if initialize and / or the callback get called 2x.

Comment: Did you figure this out because I'm having the exact same problem

Answer (score -1):

How exactly you sharing your collection?

Add console log to your collection initialize
Probably intitialize method called twice

Comment: looks ok, but anyway, try to output to console from your collection initialize...see how much times it get called